# Recover data visual studio2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-recovery

I was running my app in Visual Studio 2019 Windows Forms C#

I had very important information saved in file "Menu.json"

```
[0] StreamWriter WriteJson = new StreamWriter("Menu.json");
[1] WriteJson.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChocoMenu));
[2] WriteJson.Close();
```

I was in breakmode at line [1] and accidentally i`ve shutted the process down.

Obviously the file was clear after that

---

So the question is:
Is there a way to recover this data? 
Have VS some kind of "copy of the last programm run" or something else?

Comment: No - this is something you'd want to handle in your actual code, if you need rolling backups of data, etc.  Can you not re-run it with the same input (ChocoMenu, I would assume) to get to the same breakpoint wherein the JSON will have the contents again?

Comment: No. The app for editing a menu. The file kept info about 100+ dishes. So in this case there is no way?

Comment: So, if you were inputting all of this data during the application's run, and don't have a way to "re-inject" the exact data automatically, then you're out of luck.  Consider keeping a rolling store of the information somewhere, in case this type of thing reoccurs.